# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined Jest Testing - React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest, react-test-renderer

I have created a test file to test my following "BiddingScreen",

```
const BiddingScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {

const { currentBid } = route.params;


return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
        <Header title="BID Here" navigation={navigation} />
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.currentBid}>{CurrentBid}$</Text>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
)}
```

My test file as like follows ,

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import BiddingScreen from "../../../src/containers/biddingScreen/BiddingScreen";

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/auth');

jest.mock("react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter");


test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(< BiddingScreen />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

When I'm running my test file I got this error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

So can anyone help me to solve this problem, Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as your components props don't have defaults, you would need to mock those, something like:

```
describe('init', () => {
  test('renders correctly', () => {
    const mockedParams = {
      route: { params: { currentBid: 'whatever-id' } },
      navigation: ''
    };

    const tree = renderer.create(<BiddingScreen {...mockedParams} />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```